# Terraform Security Group (One way private communication) (Circular Dependency Issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, client-server, circular-dependency

I am currently working on a terraform script which uses bash for some server configuration and was wondering if there was a way, I could dynamically setup a security group for 2 ec2 instances where they only have a single port open to each other, with a public ip, the server is temporary and does not need an elastic IP address. Effectively what I'm after (removing a lot of the arguments) is:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "client" {
  name        = "Client"
  egress {
    from_port   = var.specific_port
    to_port     = var.specific_port
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.server.public_ip}/32"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "server" {
  name        = "Server"
  ingress {
    from_port   = var.specific_port
    to_port     = var.specific_port
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.client.public_ip}/32"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.server.id]
}

resource "aws_instance" "client" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.client.id]
}
```

In doing this however it creates a cyclical dependency as no instance can be created and return a public ip without the security group first existing and vice versa, creating a chicken and egg situation. I was wondering if there is any specific way to apply a security group to an instance later on in the terraform script after creation to avoid this cyclical dependency. Thanks for any help in advance.

============UPDATED==================

```
resource "aws_security_group" "client" {
  name        = "Client"
  egress {
    from_port   = var.specific_port
    to_port     = var.specific_port
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.server.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "server" {
  name        = "Server"
  ingress {
    from_port   = var.specific_port
    to_port     = var.specific_port
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.client.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.server.id]
}

resource "aws_instance" "client" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.client.id]
}
```

Comment: You should use security group referencing, rather then IP of the instances.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, Thanks for your suggestion, I've just tried using security groups instead and I still end up with the same cyclical dependency, just wondering if there is any way to resolve it.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using now to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `ingress` and `egress` rules with `aws_security_group_rule` resource.

In this case you can avoid circular dependencies.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "client" {
  name        = "Client"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "server" {
  name        = "Server"
}

resource "aws_instance" "server" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.server.id]
}

resource "aws_instance" "client" {
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.client.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "client_to_server_egress" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = var.specific_port
  to_port           = var.specific_port
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.client.id
  cidr_blocks       = ["${aws_instance.server.public_ip}/32"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "server_from_client_ingress" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.specific_port
  to_port           = var.specific_port
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.server.id
  cidr_blocks       = ["${aws_instance.server.public_ip}/32"]
}
```